# Csrf token verification fails between two Django web applications

Tags: django, post, csrf

I am trying to pass csrf token between two web application to make one POST data to the other.
"client" application (C) asks csrf token to "server" application (S) via a GET operation.

S responds to C with a form:

```
<form id='csrfRequestForm' name='csrfForm' action='http://{{ context_path }}/ajax/getcsrf' method='post'>
  <!-- csrf token -->
  {% csrf_token %}
  <!-- datas to POST follow -->
  ...
</form>
```

C has to submit this form to action (mapped on a url used by S) in order to POST datas to S.
When C tries to do it, csrf verification fails. I've checked GET's result and csrf token is received with the form. I have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` keyword listed under MIDDLEWARE CLASSES in `settings.py` and `RequestContext` is passed when rendering form's view with `render_to_response(... RequestContext(request))`

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to resolve it in your way, but I managed out how to do it:

C go directly to S via javascript opening a popup with:

```
window.open("http://<S_address>/<path_to_request_form>");
```

In this way, user using C that is logged via a third party authentication server (I forgot to mention it earlier, sorry), is still logged in the popup window in S and receives the form in it with a correct csrf token. I don't know if it's correct but it works.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Try defining your context and returning it like this...

```
context = RequestContext(request, {
  'request': request
})

return render_to_response(..., context_instance=context)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, and disallows for cross site POST execution.  One option you have is to mark the methods you would like to be able to execute as safe, as per the django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/